# How to fine tune gpt 3.5 on conversational data?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3, fine-tuning

My app provides emotional support to our end users. We have listeners who listen to the end users via chat. Now I have chat threads of one particular listener let say A, and he had talked with 1000 users. I want to fine tune my own model using gpt-3 in a way our listener A reponds to the users.

I have prepared this chat data thread wise, meaning there will be 1000 examples/threads if listener had talked with 1000 users. The problem fine tune allow 4096 tokens per example, so how can I give thread which is very long to be fit in 4000 tokens data limit ?

And what is the best way to train thiis conversation data if my approach is wrong ?
I am adding some data sample which I am going to use.

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "role": "system",
      "content": "Marv is a sympathetic human being who provides emoational support"
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "Hey man, how are ya?   "
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "I’m not really good right now "
    },
    {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "I’m sorry to hear that.  What’s going on? "
    },
  ]
}
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "role": "system",
      "content": "Marv is a sympathetic human being who provides emoational support"
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "I am feeling sad today"
    },
    {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "I'm sorry to hear that you're feeling sad. What happened ?"
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "My mother passed away today"
    },
    {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "Oh... really shoking to hear this. How you holding up now ?"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to fine-tune GPT 3 or GPT 3.5 Turbo?
GPT 3.5 Turbo is fine-tuned in the format your data is present in, whereas to fine-tune GPT 3, you can use the following format:

`{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}`

For your use-case, it looks like you should be looking at fine-tuning GPT 3.5 instead of GPT 3.

As of today, you will not be able to use data > 4096 tokens in your input. They will just get truncated during fine-tuning to 4096 tokens. These tokens account for every token in your input and output (chat + completion).

OpenAI may release support for fine-tuning with up to 16k tokens later in the year. As of now, I would recommend that you use examples that are within the token limit during fine-tuning and do not allow examples to get truncated. This does mean that during inference, the model expects that your input + output is within 4096 tokens.

You can refer to [Fine-tune GPT3.5](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning) for more information.